# install peer dependencies yourself

Tags: npm

npmでbuefyをインストールしたところ、以下のワーニングが出てしまいました。
自分自身で依存関係を解決しなければならないとメッセージに書いてあるようですが、具体的にはどうすれば良いのでしょうか。

```
$ npm install buefy
npm WARN buefy@0.7.2 requires a peer of vue@2.5.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ buefy@0.7.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

結論から言えば、**今回は無視して構いません**。

エラーメッセージを見てみましょう。

```
buefy@0.7.2 requires a peer of vue@2.5.x but none is installed.
```

これは`buefy@0.7.2`は`vue@2.5.x`と一緒に使用する必要があるが、`vue@2.5.x`がインストールされていないということを意味しています。

恐らく、質問者さんの状況は最新版の`vue`が既にインストールしてある状況かと思います。実は最新版の`vue`はバージョン`2.6.6`であり、`buefy`が要求する`2.5.x`に当てはまっていません。これがワーニングが出ている原因です。ですので、`vue`のバージョンを`2.5`に下げるとこのワーニングを消すことは可能です。

しかし、`2.6`がダメで`2.5`ならOKというのはとても考えにくい状況です。実際のところ`vue`側が互換性を担保しているので、`vue`の2.6を使用して何か問題が起きることはありません。したがって、これは`buefy`が`vue`の`2.5.x`を要求していること自体がおかしいと考えられます。これが、今回このワーニングを無視してよい理由です。

実際、この問題は`buefy`側で[すでに修正されています](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/pull/1220)ので、**`buefy`の新しいバージョンが出ればこのワーニングは自然に消滅します**。